# Receive message that is read read in hexadecimal

Tags: hex, arduino

I'm programming with arduino 1.0.5 in lunix/windows

With this piece of code:

```
void readSerialString () {
    char buffer[8];
    if(Serial.available()) {
        while (Serial.available()){
            sb = Serial.read();
            buffer[indexB] = sb;
            indexB++;
        }
      }
        Serial.println(buffer);

}
```

I'm trying to send (by serial terminal) a message that can be seen in hexadecimal.

For exemple if I write: "\xaa\x22\xa1"
It will not read as hexadecimal, will it?

How can I let the program read the string in input as hexadecimal?

Answer (score 1):

No your mistaking the data and it s format.
do you have access to printf ? If so use `printf("%x",char)` to see a char as hexadecimal.

**Arduino solution**
    Serial.print(78, HEX) gives "4E"

see http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print

**[edit]**

> I need the contrary of print. I need that the string that has been token from the serial terminal is interpreted as hex.

To do this use read(), but you will have to implement the convertion function from ascii HEX to data, as an HEX data for a byte hols on 2 chars, my function take two chars as input)

```
char hex_ascii_to_databyte(char c1, char c2){
    char res=0;
    if(c1>=48 && c1<=57) res = c1-48;
    else if(c1>=65&& c1<=70) res = c1 - 65 + 0xa;
    else if(c1>=97&& c1<=102) res = c1 - 97 + 0xa;
    else{//error
    }
    //idem c2 in res2
    res=res<<4;
    res+=res2;
    return res;
}
```

for each hex read, call twice read (to read the 2 ascii chars) then call this func

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I don't have access to printf. In realty I don't want to print as hex, but I want that the input is read as an hex.

Comment: I added the arduino solution too

Comment: Yes, I've read, but I need the contrary of print. I need that the string that has been token from the serial terminal is interpreted as hex.

Comment: Interesting! I'm going to try it! Thank you!

Comment: check the value in ascii table in case I made  a mistake.

Comment: What will happen when the char in input are odd? Ok, I will try and answer here.

Comment: Then you should decide what value to return to not fail, just choose a default value like 0 for instance. It all depends what you do of your data after

Comment: mmm... I got error (in the else I've inserted: `Serial.println("Error");`). I'm going to check where is the mistake.

Comment: maybe this is a special char (like '\n')